# Converting springs and struts to autolayout

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I'm in the middle of converting an older Cocoa project to use auto layout and I sometimes have trouble doing things that used to be real easy with springs and struts (which I understand well) and not so easy or obvious with auto-layout.

Is there any sort of guide/table that can help convert between springs and struts and auto-layout constraints. I couldn't find any such thing so far.

For example, in the past I would align a view to the left by setting the following mask:
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
Or, if I wanted the view to stretch horizontally I would set the mask
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
What would be the auto-layout equivalent?

Comment: Are you looking for storyboard tutorial or Code tutorial for auto layouts ?

Comment: I'm looking for some resource that explains auto-layout from the perspective of spring and struts.